# Connect Oracle 11g to proprietory OLEDB data source

Tags: oracle11g, oledb, consumer

I have an Oracle 11g database, which connects to another Oracle database and has stored procedures to collect data from that source database. The source database is being replaced with a proprietory (OSISoft PI) database which has an OLEDB data provider and I have the task of maintaining the connection. So...

I can see lots of info about an Oracle OLEDB provider allowing Oracle to be a source but nothing about Oracle being a consumer. So...

Can Oracle 11g connect to an OLEDB data source in order for stored procedures in Oracle to query the OLEDB source?

Comment: It should be possible as soon as you install Osisoft PI OLEDB interface on the platform of your Oracle DB that execute the stored procedures.
Keep in mind that Osisoft PI is not a relational DB, you have to keep queries very simples, like "SELECT value, timestamp from valuestable where tag='TAGNAME and timestamp between X and Y".

Comment: Link to some PI OLEDB Interface doc (too long to fit into last answer) https://livelibrary.osisoft.com/LiveLibrary/content/en/oledb-ent-v4/GUID-1B002EDE-B0AB-4BC9-A3C9-65F440D3B32D#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-C1EC76CB-7DCD-4548-8269-D8DF21451701.xml&docid=GUID-1B002EDE-B0AB-4BC9-A3C9-65F440D3B32D&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-1B002EDE-B0AB-4BC9-A3C9-65F440D3B32D